# How to run command on connect to network

Tags: wireless, networking, command-line, autostart, automation

How can I automatically run a command whenever my computer connects to a network?

I want it to run in these situations:

1. On power on and login to Unity
2. On waking up from suspend or hibernate
3. When it connects to a network after disconnection

I first tried the /etc/pm/sleep.d/ for suspend and hibernate, but they run before computer connects to the network and because my command is a transaction in the network, It doesn't work at all. I even tried applying "sleep 10" to the first of command, but It caused 10 second of delay before connecting to the network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look inside the `/etc/network` directory. There are some directories where you can insert your scripts:

```
$ ls /etc/network
if-down.d  if-post-down.d  if-pre-up.d  if-up.d  interfaces  run
```

- `if-down.d` – before interfaces are down
- `if-post-down.d` – after interfaces are down
- `if-pre-up.d` – before ifcs are up
- `if-up.d` – after ifcs are up